# Добавить библиотеку Google Play Services в AIDE (libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx, aide

Добрый день, есть необходимость добавить рекламу в проект, через Gradle это можно было сделать в 1 строчку, но как быть с libGDX без понятия, пробовал прописывать путь до папки с распакованной библиотекой - выдавало ошибку в самой либе.
Пробовал гуглить либу в `.jar`, находил, но опять выдавало ошибку, но на этот раз с `android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"`.
Есть ли у кого-нибудь возможность дать мне `com.google.android.gms` последней версии или кинуть ссылку, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было поставить несколько либ от гп, т.к. они раздербанили одну на кучу...